# DXA 1.2 installation and configuration

Tags: configuration, dxa, broker, installation

I am installing DXA1.2 with Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1. Following are the steps that I had followed.

1. Imported the SDL Digital Experience Accelerator Publications using
   Content porter. (Powershell import were causing few issues due to
   third-party authentication and content porter is configured in mixed
   mode)
2. Published the example website (including navigation)
3. Installed the web application using the following PowerShell (version 5.0)
4. Copied the ojdbc7.jar to the bin directory
5. Copied the  cd_licenses.xml from a working CD wesbite
6. I manually edited the cd_dynamic_conf and cd_link_conf files to
   include localhost instead of the server name (which defaulted to include server name during
   the install)

Following is the script used for installation of the web application

```
& '.\Install Web-Application.ps1' -webName "myDXAWebsite"
-defaultDbServer "MYDBSERVER" -defaultDbType "ORACLESQL" -defaultDbPort "MYPORT" -defaultDbName "MYDBNAME" -defaultDbUser "BROKERDBSCHEMA" -defaultDbPassword "BROKERDBPASSWORD" -deployType "Staging" -distDestination "D:\Inetpub\myDXAWebsite" -logFolder "D:\logs\DXA" -logLevel "All" -siteDomain "" -siteLogFile "D:/logs/DXA/site.log" -sitePort "12345" -sitePublicationId "MYPUBLICATIONID" -sessionDbServer "MYDBSERVER" -sessionDbType "ORACLESQL" -sessionDbPort "MYPORT" -sessionDbName "MYDBNAME"
-sessionDbUser "SESSIONUSERSCHEMA" -sessionDbPassword "SESSIONUSERPASSWROD" -traceLogFile "D:/logs/DXA/trace.log"
-webSiteAction "Recreate"
```

I am trying to access the index page (http://localhost:12345/index) while I receive the following exception in the site.log.

```
015-12-02 13:53:13,188 [6] ERROR - 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2015-12-02 13:53:13,251 [6] ERROR - Internal Server Error
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error ---> Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Error loading binary for URL '/version.json' ---> Java.Lang.Exception
```

For now, I have jodbc7.jar in my application's lib directory and noticed that it is able to connect to the broker without any issues. Following is the log from the cd_core.log

```
015-12-02 13:53:06,848 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - java.specification.version = 1.7
2015-12-02 13:53:06,848 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - java.class.path = D:\Inetpub\Dxa-shiva\bin\config;D:\Inetpub\Dxa-shiva\bin\bin;D:\Inetpub\Dxa-shiva\bin\lib\activation.jar;D:\Inetpub\Dxa-shiva\bin\lib\antlr.jar;etc
```

The license has been successfully validated as well

```
2015-12-02 13:53:06,944 DEBUG SystemValidator - Testing license for product: Tridion CD Broker
2015-12-02 13:53:06,944 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - 
2015-12-02 13:53:06,945 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - ********************************************************************************
2015-12-02 13:53:06,945 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - Checking if product Tridion CD Storage is enabled....
```

Below is the configuration from cd_storage. defaultdb is pointing to the Oracle broker database.

```
<Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb" />
<Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb" />
```

Following are the logs from cd_core.log trying to retrieve an item. No Errors are reported except from cd_core.log

```
2015-12-02 13:53:12,880 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Default storage provider has caching set to: false
2015-12-02 13:53:12,880 INFO  StorageManagerTransactionMonitor - Starting storage transaction monitoring
2015-12-02 13:53:12,880 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loaded following dao Properties[publication=263, typeMapping=BinaryVariant, storageId=defaultdb, cached=false] for publication/typeMapping/itemExtension: 263 / BinaryVariant / null
2015-12-02 13:53:12,880 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loading a non cached DAO for publicationId/typeMapping/itemExtension: 263 / BinaryVariant / null
2015-12-02 13:53:12,881 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Wrapping DAO's, currently 1 wrappers installed
2015-12-02 13:53:12,881 INFO  SessionWrapperFactory - Running Session Wrapping mechanism
2015-12-02 13:53:12,893 DEBUG SessionManagerImpl - No claim store!!! Ambient framework is probably not enabled!
2015-12-02 13:53:12,893 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2015-12-02 13:53:13,239 DEBUG BinaryMetaFactory - Finding binary by url 263 ,/version.json
2015-12-02 13:53:13,239 DEBUG SessionManagerImpl - No claim store!!! Ambient framework is probably not enabled!
2015-12-02 13:53:13,240 DEBUG SessionProxyMethodHandler - Intercepted call to 'findByURL' while not in session.
2015-12-02 13:53:13,612 DEBUG HttpModule - Init
2015-12-02 13:53:13,612 DEBUG HttpModule - Init
```

The are no exceptions in the event logs.

Am I missing any configuration? Are there any additional steps that should be done, if I do content port the publications vs. using powershell for implementing CM import? 
Are there any queries that I can run (similar to the application) against the broker to verify if all items are being retrieved?

**Update I**

I could not find any content deployed to the filesystem as well. My storage configurations are above.

Publishing of HTML Design is successful. [image]

**Update II**

The items are available in the broker database but I still receive the above error.

```
SELECT * FROM PAGE WHERE PUBLICATION_ID = 283
SELECT * FROM BINARYVARIANTS WHERE PUBLICATION_ID = 283
```

Comment: Is everything in the Deployer configured correctly? (To publish to the database) and have you also published the HTML design? (Version.json is part of the HTML design artifacts ), last can you confirm there is actually pages and binaries available in the broker database, to make sure publishing was successful?

Comment: I have updated my question based on your comment Bart. I was looking at the GitHub code (https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Statics/BinaryFileManager.cs : Line 163) as well. Do you have a query that I can verify against my broker based on the code?

Comment: On my phone atm, so not having the exact query but check the binary_variants table for a file name version.json. Looking at the pages it looks like it should be there so then I'd doublecheck the cd_dynamic conf if the correct publication ID and URL mapping is there.

Comment: The item is available in the broker DB as well. The publication ID and URL Mapping is available in cd_dynamic.conf.

Comment: Apparently, a (Java) exception occurs in BinaryMetaFactory.GetMetaByUrl. Unfortunately, the details of the exception don't bubble up through DD4T.  A way to further analyze the issue is to attach a debugger and make it break when exceptions are thrown. That allows you to inspect the details of the original exception.

Comment: So, you found an answer to your original problem. Would be better to answer your own question and create a new question for your new problem (for which you apparently also found a solution already?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had used -defaultDbName "MYDBNAME" in my install script. That inserted the following code in my cd_storage.

```
<Property Value="DATABASENAME" Name="databaseName"/>
```

We use sevice name to connect to our Oracle database. i.e;

```
<Property Value="SERVICENAME" Name="serviceName"/>
```

Once I corrected this, I was able to retrieve the site from the broker database.

Thanks to Bart and Rick for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This is becoming a bit messy, I agree with Rick that it probabaly is better if you answer the initial problem here yourself and accept that.

Your second question is indeed already answered by me stackexchange.com/questions/11342/tri-adding-new-vocabularies/11343#11343

It shouldn;t matter if you import with Content Porter or the powershell script, since eventually both use the ImportExport API. When you import, you must have the Application Data file available as described, and then Content Porter should also import the Application Data for you automatically.

What went wrong there is most likely too late to investigate, so you can better focus on fixing it by either:

1. rerun the import again (via CP or the script, but check the log at the end if it added the application data, when you use CP, just keep everything selected from the export package as suggested by CP, so next, next, next...)
2. Manually set the application data as described in my answer mentioned
3. Delete and start from scratch (but #1 should probably be okay in most cases)

Comment: Thanks Bart. I followed 3 and still ended with the same error. I will post a different question.